# parsing xml file in unix

Tags: xml, parsing, shell, unix

I've got this xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<RunInfo xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Version="2">
  <Run Id="130514_M01481_0011_000000000-A3F7W" Number="10">
    <Flowcell>000000000-A3F7W</Flowcell>
    <Instrument>M01481</Instrument>
    <Date>130514</Date>
    <Reads>
      <Read NumCycles="151" Number="1" IsIndexedRead="N" />
      <Read NumCycles="8" Number="2" IsIndexedRead="Y" />
      <Read NumCycles="8" Number="3" IsIndexedRead="Y" />
      <Read NumCycles="151" Number="4" IsIndexedRead="N" />
    </Reads>
    <FlowcellLayout LaneCount="1" SurfaceCount="2" SwathCount="1" TileCount="14" />
  </Run>
</RunInfo>
```

I need to write a shell script that loops through the 'Reads' and extracts the NumCycles for the IsIndexedRead="N" and IsIndexedRead="Y".  I used xmllint with this command:

```
xmllint --xpath 'string(//Read/@NumCycles)' RunInfo.xml
```

That gave 151, but I need to loop through the reads.  Anyone knows a better way?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`xmllint --xpath '//Read[@IsIndexedRead = "Y"]/@NumCycles' RunInfo.xml | grep -o '[0-9]\+'`:

```
8
8
```

`xmllint --xpath '//Read[@IsIndexedRead = "N"]/@NumCycles' RunInfo.xml | grep -o '[0-9]\+'`:

```
151
151
```

Comment: That just prints "XPath set is empty" on my system. EDIT: to be precise, that XPath works in Python/lxml but fails with xmllint.

Comment: More precisely, xmllint --xpath 'string(//Read[@IsIndexedRead = "N"]/@NumCycles)' will give me the value.  Thanks!

Comment: @kampu just run what I posted above and that should give you back 151.

Comment: I see. But didn't you want *both* IndexedRead="N" nodes, not just one of them?

Comment: Thanks @l0b0.  do you know how I can put each value as a variable in shell? So I want the 8 to be a variable and the other 8 to be another variable.

Comment: You could use parameter-expansion (check the bash manpage) to erase out the number on the left of the space in one case, and then erase out the number on the right of the space in the other case

Comment: @bioinf80 What are you actually trying to do? In non-ancient versions of Bash you can use an array like `values=($(command))` if `command` outputs whitespace-separated values like above.